# Python (Tkinter) How can I display Mysql record only and no list?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I am new to Python and I am working on a test script to display only the mysql record with little formatting - I should not be using 'tree' I assume as a start.  Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import pymysql as mdb
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()  
root.title("eCOMMAND")
root.minsize(800,500)
root.geometry("1200x800")


tree = ttk.Treeview(root)

# Database Call
dbi = mdb.connect("localhost",port=3306, user="user", passwd="*****", db="index_db" )
cursor = dbi.cursor()

tree["columns"] = ("one", "two", "three")
tree.column("one", width=100)
tree.column("two", width=100)
tree.column("three", width=100)


cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM caution_elements""")
dbi.commit()

cpt = 0 
tree.insert('', 'end', values=(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
cpt += 1 # increment the ID
tree.pack()

photo = PhotoImage(file="test.png")
label = Label(root,image=photo)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I have include my entire test script.  I am able to display the listed records however I do not want a empty box above (the row for description) or empty vertical column - I only want and require the cell data. So if I only called a record it would display only that box of data.

I would like to display data much like you would call php in css (php include) less that of calling a second php script result but more direct if possible.

Comment: I'm confused as to what the problem is? Are you not displaying the information in the tkinter window the way you would like or are you not collecting data from the SQL file the way you would like?

Comment: If would help if your [mcve] didn't require a database connection. Since the question seems to be about displaying the information rather than fetching the data, you can hard-code some data that is in the exact same format as returned by `cursor.execute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question right, you want to get rid of the first column and the headings of the `Treeview`.

What you need is the `show` option of the treeview:

- with `show='tree headings'` (the default) both are displayed,
- with `show='tree'` only the first column is displayed but not the headings,
- ...

So, to achieve what you want, all you have to do is
`tree.configure(show='')`

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry about the confusion.  Yes I have no issues regarding the retrieving or fetching of data or displaying it via Tkinter.  This issue is simply that my display of that data was more structured than I needed. I only wish to display the data with without any framing or labelling.  By displaying just the data it could act almost as a status or alert on the screen. I will try the tree.configure and update with my success.

Comment: The tree option allows for not specific area for description but I dont want the framing only the data cell. Is this possible?

Comment: I tried tree.configure(show='tree'), I do loose the top section but still have the empty left column  ie |       | data | data | data |   I just want ie | data | data | data

Comment: I just got what you were recommending tree.configure(show='') worked perfectly!! Thanks